# Почему при ресайзе одно значение пересчитывается, а другое нет?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если кликнуть по "Click", body и wrap применяться свойства transform: translate3d(0px, 54px, 0px) и transform: translate3d(0px, -54px, 0px) соответственно. Если затем отресайзить окно (меньше 1366px), то у body значение изменится, а у wrap нет. Т.е. будет transform: translate3d(0px, 18px, 0px) и transform: translate3d(0px, -18px, 0px). Почему так происходит? Как сделать чтобы оба значения менялись?

```js
function wrapMenu(e) {
   var menuHeight = $('.wrap').height();
   e.preventDefault();
   var mnu = $(this).prev();
   $('body').css(
    {"transform": "translate3d(0px, " + menuHeight + "px, 0px)"}
   );

   mnu.css(
    {"transform": "translate3d(0px, " + -menuHeight + "px, 0px)"}
   );

 }

$('.click').on('click', wrapMenu);

$(window).on( 'resize', wrapMenu );
```

```css
@media (max-width: 1366px) {
  ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem1</li>
    <li>Lorem1</li>
    <li>Lorem1</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<span class="click">Click</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что при ресайзе окна, у вас `this` - это `window`. Соответственно `$(this).prev()` не существует.

Используйте селектор, что бы достать необходимый элемент.

```js
function wrapMenu(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var mnu = $('.wrap');
  var menuHeight = mnu.height();
  $('body').css({
    "transform": "translate3d(0px, " + menuHeight + "px, 0px)"
  });

  mnu.css({
    "transform": "translate3d(0px, " + -menuHeight + "px, 0px)"
  });

}

$('.click').on('click', wrapMenu);

$(window).on('resize', wrapMenu);
```

```css
@media (max-width: 1366px) {
  ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem1</li>
    <li>Lorem1</li>
    <li>Lorem1</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<span class="click">Click</span>
```